# removing an item from a list in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

How would you update a list by removing the first item?

consider the following pseudocode

```
define remover
(list = cdr list))
```

or is there a more recommendable way of removing the first item in a list?

Comment: You're on the right track, you just need to reformulate your idea in correct Scheme syntax.

Comment: could I accomplish that by doing 
(let list (cdr list))?

Comment: Not quite, the `let` form is *not* an assignment, but a new binding for the name that exists from the start of the `let` form to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nailed it, just write it as a procedure:

```
(define (remover lst)
  (cdr l))
```

And use it like this (this creates a new binding, and is *not* an assignment):

```
(let ((new-list (remover old-list)))
  new-list)
```

Or like this (this defines a new list):

```
(define new-list (remover old-list))
```

In any case, be aware that the original list passed as a parameter to `remover` will not be modified, instead a *new list* will be returned without the first element of the *old list*; that's the way to operate on immutable linked lists, you should never assume that any modifications on a list will occur in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Beware!

There are no list data structure per se. So you can not take a list, `l`, and remove the first element of `l`.

What you can do, when given a list `l`, is to use `cdr` to produce a new list which has the same elements as `l` does, except that the new list doesn't hold the first element.

A little more detail: A list holding the three values 1, 2, and, 3 is represented as   `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))`.
Let us name the cons-cells:

```
       c3 = (cons 3 '()) 
       c2 = (cons 2 c3)
   l = c1 = (cons 1 c2)
```

The first thing to note is that the entire list is given by the value c1.
We can not delete the number 1 from the list by manipulating the cons-cell c1. 
We can however easily find a list omitting the first element, since

```
   c2 = (cons 2 c3) = (cons 2 (cons 3 '())
```

Therefore `(cdr l) = (cdr c1) = c2` will produce a new list omitting the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what `cdr` does. Remember, `cdr` returns a list. Your answer is close, you just need to think about it in terms of Scheme syntax and functions.