# remove file name if it is already in the list

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to remove an item (file name) from a list, nothing I have done works, no remove functions from the documentation, nothing from this website.. here is my code:

```
#lang racket

(define file-collection '())

(for ([f (directory-list)] #:when (regexp-match? "\\.log$" f))  
  (set! file-collection (foldr cons (list f) file-collection)))

(define (check-file file-in) 
  (for/list ([i (file->lines file-in)]) 
  (cond ((equal? i "[robot warrior]") (remove file-in file-collection) ))))

(for ([i file-collection])(check-file i))
```

still, no matter what I try, file-collection remains the same and all files are included in the collection.. however, if i use displayln file-in, only the files without [robot warrior] are displayed, and that's perfect, thats what I need, but I need to store it somehow. I find it very odd/weird how it refuses to work.

Comment: something like this doesn't work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468151/removing-an-item-from-a-list-in-scheme

Answer (score 1):

Here is two ways to remove certain files from a list.

```
#lang racket

(define all-files '("file1" "file2" "file3" "file4"))

(for/list ([file all-files]
           #:unless (equal? file "file2"))
  file)

(filter (lambda (file) (not (equal? file "file2")))
        all-files)
```

The result is:

```
'("file1" "file3" "file4")
'("file1" "file3" "file4")
```

Note that both `for/list` and `filter` rather han removing elements from an existing list produces new lists with the same elements (and omitting "file2" in this case).

Comment: what's the purpose of "file" in here? little lost.. this does not remove anything from the file-collection list? also if it's not to much of a bother, could you tell me why the remove method as taken from the documentation wont do what it's supposed to do?

Comment: (for/list ([file all-files]) ...) will loop through the elements in the list `all-files`. First `file` will refer to the first element, then `file` will refer to the second element etc. Try `(for/list ([x (list 1 2 3 4)]) (* 2 x))` to see how `for/list` works.

Comment: So `file` is just a name here. I could have used `f` as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can implement this in my code, it appears to be different from what I'm attempting to do. Here you are checking file names, whereas my script is checking for a string in a list of files and remove a file from the list that contains the string.. sorry, I just don't know how to implement this :/ but thanks for the time, will up vote.

Comment: @disaster999 are you asking how to read all the text in these files - and to remove a file from the list that contains a phrase? Or asking how to filter the names of files like soegaard provided?